# Where do I change the monster power?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the new patch for diablo 3 you can supposedly change the monster power at the quest screen, but I am unable to find where you can do that. Does anyone know where to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about historical gameplay which is no longer accessible.

Answer (score 11):

You have to enable this first in the setting screen under gameplay settings. Then you get to choose the monster power when you start a new game.

[image]

Image taken from [the official blog post on the feature](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6187857/Monster_Power_More_Guts_More_Glory-11_10_2012).

Comment: can you please update this answer for patch 2.0?  You don't need the option anymore, and its now in the game settings for t1-t6

Comment: @z- Isn't the entire question obsolete now that monster power doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: yea, i'm not sure how to handle it either.  Do we want to revise it for torment or just add the lable that its obselete?

Comment: @z- I'd probably delete the question entirely, MP is dead and there is no way to play an old version.